# How do I loop through a json array, and then display the results in an discord js embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Thanks for taking a peek at my question. This is my first question, so hopefully I do all the right stuff.

I am using DiscordJS/NodeJS

I have a large(ish) json file that has a list of maps/links to download the map, and an extra field.

```
[
  {
    "name": "2 Evil Eyes",
    "link": "http://",
    "extra": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "25 To Life",
    "link": "http://",
    "extra": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Back To School",
    "link": "http://",
    "extra": ""
  },
```

I created this file myself from a list that was given to me.

The goal of this file was to be able to display the data (maps, link, extra) in a discord embed. I know that having 70+ .addField(s) is not a great idea, but it is what was requested.

So I thought that I would just have a little loop through and display the data that way, but my issue is that it keeps posting an embed for each result it gets. Here is my code below:

```
fs.readFile('./maps.json', 'utf-8', function(err, data){
        json = JSON.parse(data);
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            let name = data[i].name;
            let link = data[i].link;
            let extra = data[i].extra;

        }
        const mapRot = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Map Details")
            .setAuthor(client.user.username)
            .setDescription("These are your maps for the night.")
            .addField("Maps", name)
            .addField("Link", link)
            .addField("Extra", extra);

        message.channel.send(mapRot);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not too familiar with the Discord API, however, it seems as though you can do something like [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor), where you pass to `addFields` a list of arguments.

So I would think you could first [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through the array to transform the data, and then pass it in as it should be specified to `addFields`. Something along the lines of:

```
fs.readFile('./maps.json', 'utf-8')
.then(JSON.parse)
.then(data => data.map((entry) => { 
   // here, 'entry' stores an object of the form:
   // {
   // "name": "2 Evil Eyes",
   // "link": "http://",
   // "extra": ""
   // }
   // and per the Discord documentation, needs to return
   // an object of the form:
   // { 
   // "name": 'Inline field title', 
   // "value": 'Some value here'
   // }


   // for example:
   return { name: entry.name, value: entry.value }
}))
.then((parsedEntries) => {
new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Map Details")
            .setAuthor(client.user.username)
            .setDescription("These are your maps for the night.")
            .addFields(...parsedEntries)

// that last .addFields call is expecting parsedEntries to be of the form 
// [{name: "field name", value: "field value"}, {name: "field2", value: "field2value"}]
})
```

Edit: essentially, you have a list of objects with properties that look like this:

```
{
   "name": "2 Evil Eyes",
   "link": "http://",
   "extra": ""
}
```

But `addFields` takes objects with properties that look like this:

```js
{
   "name": "Field title"
   "value": "Field value"
}
```

So you can use the JavaScript map function to `map` over each entry in the list, converting objects from your original format as specified in your `maps.json` file to the one that the Discord API requires.

[Here](https://codeburst.io/learn-understand-javascripts-map-function-ffc059264783)'s an article that might help introduce the essential concept of JavaScript mapping if you aren't previously familiar with it.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for reply. Sorry, I don't mean to be all like _do it for me_, but what do you mean on the `take each entry and return of the form`.

Comment: No problem! I've added some more clarification to my answer with some annotations in the code, let me know if that is helpful! I'm not too familiar with the Discord API, but my understanding is you want to pass to the embed object in [this](https://imgur.com/a/ZFOSnu5) format.